# Still going to or going to still?

Tags: tenses

I'm translating something into english from a teen fiction novel and there's a scene in it where one boy drops his sandwich and his friend, grossed out, asks if he still wants to eat it.

What is correct/sounds more natural?

> 1. "You're not still gonna eat that, right?"
> 2. "You're not gonna still eat that, right?"

Comment: *You’re not gonna eat that still, are you?* sounds more natural to me. Note I wouldn’t use *right?* as the tag in this sentence, or either of your versions.

Answer (score 2):

**Either is correct.**

There is no difference in the sentences because the adverb *still* ends up modifying the verb "are going" either way. The slight problem with choosing the second sentence, though, is that it splits the infinitive *to eat*. Some grammar sticklers classify split infinitives as misplaced modifiers, but [modern-day experts](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/split-infinitives) now largely agree that it is not wrong.

However, coming from a native speaker, it sounds less natural to place the adverbs *not* and *still* next to each other like that.

Answer (score 0):

The use of *right* as a tag in your sentence seems off, I would use *are you?* Saying that, I would also move *still* to right before the tag, with the result

> You’re not gonna eat that still, are you?

which is what, as a native speaker of American English, I would say in this situation. To me, it’s more naturally sounding then either of your two versions. I think it’s because placing *still* at the end of the main part of the sentence emphasizes the eating of the sandwich even after the given situation of having dropped it on the floor, akin to

> You’re not going to eat that *(even) after having dropped it on the floor,* are you?

Your two versions are both grammatical but come across as unnatural, or at least ‘marked’ in the given context.